# Momentum as ladder operator in CFT

Tags: operators, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, commutator, scale-invariance

I'm following these lectures: https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000.

In eq, 3.19 the author writes
$$
[D,\mathcal{O}(0)] =-i\Delta \mathcal{O}(0),\tag{3.19}
$$
where $D$ is the generator of dilations and $\mathcal{O}(0)$ is an operator inserted in the origin with dimension $\Delta$.
In the following eq. 3.20 he computes $D |\Delta\rangle$, where $|\Delta\rangle =\mathcal{O}(0) |0\rangle$ is the state related to $\mathcal{O}(0)$ by the state-operator correspondence. Since $D|0\rangle =0$ we simply have (using the equation above)
$$
D |\Delta\rangle =D \mathcal{O}(0)|0\rangle =[D, \mathcal{O}(0)]|0\rangle =-i\Delta \mathcal{O}(0) |0\rangle =-i\Delta |\Delta\rangle.
$$
Instead, he has a different sign in the last term. This is important, because this sign implies that $P_\mu$ is a lowering operator and not rising; if $[D,P_\mu]=iP_\mu$ (eq. 3.22) we obtain
$$
DP_\mu |\Delta\rangle =[D,P_\mu] |\Delta\rangle +P_\mu D|\Delta\rangle =iP_\mu |\Delta\rangle -i\Delta P_\mu |\Delta\rangle =-i(\Delta-1)P_\mu |\Delta\rangle,
$$
i.e. the state $P_\mu |\Delta\rangle$ has dimension $\Delta-1$, in contradiction with the author.

Could anybody help me understanding what is going on?

Comment: Oh, I think the answer is here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340563/ladder-structure-of-d2-cft?rq=1.

Comment: The author does indeed make a mistake by changing sign, but $D$ and $P_\mu$ acting on the Hilbert space are different from the operator acting on the space of functions, and in particular their commutator has opposite sign compared to $[D,P_\mu]$. Using different letters $\mathcal{D} \mathcal{P}_\mu|\Delta \rangle =[\mathcal{D},\mathcal{P}_\mu] \Delta \rangle+ \mathcal{P}_\mu \mathcal{D} \Delta \rangle =-i \mathcal{P}_\mu |\Delta \rangle -i \Delta\mathcal{P}_\mu |\Delta \rangle =-i(\Delta+1)\mathcal{P}_\mu |\Delta \rangle$.