# CFT Radial Quantization Raising and Lowering Operators Sign Question

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, momentum, conformal-field-theory, commutator

Following [Slava Rychkov](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-319-43626-5) (Page 41, [Or here on arxiv page 39](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05000)), I am trying to show that the momentum operator raises the scaling dimension.
I've seen the other related questions on this matter by [Y. Sliv](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/340563/) and [Rubilax96](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/725966/) but they all seem to have missed a critical point.
As Rychkov wrote $\left[D,\mathcal{O}\left(0\right)\right]=-i\Delta\mathcal{O}\left(0\right)$ in (3.19) I understand that the sign flips when the operators are acting on states and not functions:
$$\left[a,b\right]\left|\psi\right\rangle =ab\left|\psi\right\rangle -ba\left|\psi\right\rangle =aB\left|\psi\right\rangle -bA\left|\psi\right\rangle =Ba\left|\psi\right\rangle -Ab\left|\psi\right\rangle =BA\left|\psi\right\rangle -AB\left|\psi\right\rangle =\left[B,A\right]\left|\psi\right\rangle$$
So now we have $\left[D,\mathcal{O}\left(0\right)\right]=i\Delta\mathcal{O}\left(0\right)$ (if we stick to the previous answers) and:
$$D\left|\Delta\right\rangle =D\mathcal{O}_{\Delta}\left(0\right)\left|0\right\rangle =\left[D,\mathcal{O}_{\Delta}\left(0\right)\right]\left|0\right\rangle +\mathcal{O}_{\Delta}\left(0\right)D\left|0\right\rangle =i\Delta\mathcal{O}_{\Delta}\left(0\right)\left|0\right\rangle =i\Delta\left|\Delta\right\rangle$$
But now as I try to show that the momentum is the raising operator I need also to flip the sign of $\left[D,P_{\mu}\right]=iP_{\mu}$ to $\left[D,P_{\mu}\right]=-iP_{\mu}$ (In the answers to the other questions they only flip one of them). So now
$$DP_{\mu}\left|\Delta\right\rangle =\left[D,P_{\mu}\right]\left|\Delta\right\rangle +P_{\mu}D\left|\Delta\right\rangle =-iP_{\mu}\left|\Delta\right\rangle +i\Delta P_{\mu}\left|\Delta\right\rangle =i\left(\Delta-1\right)P_{\mu}\left|\Delta\right\rangle$$
Seems to be the lowering operator. Is there a mistake in my calculations? Or does the sign not flip on one of the commutators and why? Is the momentum not the raising operator in this basis?

Comment: I'm entirely confused as to how you got $D | \Delta \rangle = i \Delta | \Delta \rangle$. You've yourself said earlier in your question that $[D , {\cal O} ] = - i \Delta {\cal O}$ but then later you say $[ D , {\cal O} ] = + i \Delta {\cal O}$. Stick to one convention and follow that throughout to be consistent. Based on Slava's convention, you should be getting $D | \Delta \rangle = - i \Delta | \Delta \rangle$

Comment: I've edited the question, maybe it will be less confusing for you now. If you stick to Slava's convention throughout (which he doesn't elaborate algebraically about) you will get that $DP_{\mu}\left|\Delta\right\rangle =-i\left(\Delta-1\right)P_{\mu}\left|\Delta\right\rangle$ which still doesn't answer my question as of how is it consistent with what he is saying next (saying that it is a raising operator).
That is why I've been trying to modify it using the answers to the other questions.

Comment: Start by explaining exactly how you got $D|\Delta\rangle = i \Delta | \Delta \rangle$ if the commutator is given by $[D , {\cal O} ] = - i \Delta {\cal O}$. Your proof is incorrect.

Comment: The commutation relation flips a sign when it's acting on states not on functions. It is consistent with Salva's book, he also writes it with a minus at first. But as you will see when he does the computation he doesn't write a minus.

Comment: There is no sign flip in the commutator of the conformal generators. You have most definitely misunderstood something. What does happen is that if there are **differential operators** ${\cal A}$, ${\cal B}$ and ${\cal C}$ which satisfy the algebra $[ {\cal A} , {\cal B} ] = {\cal C}$, then the **generators** $A$, $B$ and $C$ act on local operators via $-{\cal A}$, $-{\cal B}$ and $-{\cal C}$ respectively. This has nothing to do with the flip in sign of any commutator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Proof that $P_\mu$ is a raising operator**

The whole calculation can be done entirely talking about operators *in the Hilbert space*. On the one hand, in equation (3.17) Slava gives us the adjoint action of conformal generators on primary fields. Of interest here is $[D,{\cal O}(0)] = -i \Delta {\cal O}(0)$. On the other hand in equation (2.6) he gives us the conformal algebra. Of interest here is $[D,P_\mu] = {\color{red}-}iP_\mu$.

Let us assume therefore that $$[D,{\cal O}(0)] = -i \Delta {\cal O}(0),\quad [D,P_\mu] = -i P_\mu\tag{1}$$

then we have that \begin{equation}\begin{split}[D,[P_\mu,{\cal O}(0)]] &= [D,P_\mu{\cal O}(0)]-[D,{\cal O}(0)P_\mu]\\
&=P_\mu[D,{\cal O}(0)]+[D,P_\mu]{\cal O}(0)-{\cal O}(0)[D,P_\mu]-[D,{\cal O}(0)]P_\mu\\
&=-i\Delta P_\mu {\cal O}(0)-iP_\mu {\cal O}(0)+i{\cal O}(0)P_\mu +i\Delta {\cal O}(0)P_\mu\\
&=-i\Delta (P_\mu{\cal O}(0)-{\cal O}(0)P_\mu)-i(P_\mu{\cal O}(0)-{\cal O}(0)P_\mu)\\
&=-i\Delta[P_\mu,{\cal O}(0)]-i[P_\mu,{\cal O}(0)]\\
&= -i(\Delta + 1) [P_\mu,{\cal O}(0)].\end{split}\tag{2}\end{equation}

As a result, $P_\mu$ indeed raises the eigenvalue of the dilatation operator. Your whole mistake is that you used $[D,P_\mu]=+iP_\mu$ while you needed to have $[D,P_\mu]=-iP_\mu$ as per Slava's conventions in his notes, see again equation (2.6).

Finally, about the state. Observe that assuming $|\Omega\rangle$ is the conformally invariant vacuum $$D|\Delta\rangle = D{\cal O}(0)|\Omega\rangle = (D{\cal O}(0)-{\cal O}(0)D)|\Omega\rangle = [D,{\cal O}(0)]|\Omega\rangle = -i\Delta {\cal O}(0)|\Omega\rangle = -i\Delta|\Delta\rangle,\tag{3}$$
where we have used that the conformal generators, and in particular $D$, annihilate the vacuum. If your convention is that $[D,{\cal O}(0)]=-i\Delta{\cal O}(0)$ then necessarily $D|\Delta\rangle = -i\Delta|\Delta\rangle$ as explained by Prahar as well in comments.

**Algebra of operators in the Hilbert space vs. differential operators**

All that said, the confusion seems to be in the distinction between the Hilbert space generators and the associated differential operators. I will phrase this analysis in a much more general way for the benefit of the OP.

Let us suppose that there exists operators $Q_i$ in the Hilbert space of the theory that satisfy some algebra $$[Q_i,Q_j]=c_{ij}^k Q_k.\tag{4}$$

These operators act on states in the Hilbert space and can act on other operators through the commutator. Let us further assume that there are operators in the Hilbert space that are fields, like ${\cal O}(x)$. These depend on $x$ and the operators $Q_i$ are *supposed here* to act on them by differential operators:

$$[Q_i,{\cal O}(x)]={\mathscr Q}_i{\cal O}(x)\tag{5}.$$

It is important to realize the distinction between $Q_i$ and $\mathscr{Q}_i$: the operator $Q_i$ is an operator in the Hilbert space, it acts on states. The operator $\mathscr{Q}_i$ is an operator in a space of functions of $x$, its action is on the $x$ dependence of functions and since ${\cal O}(x)$ depends on $x$ it can act on them. Note, in particular, that $[Q_i,Q_j]$ is a commutator in the space of operators in the Hilbert space whereas $[{\mathscr Q}_i,{\mathscr Q}_j]$ is a commutator in the space of operators acting on functions of $x$. **Appreciate that $Q_i$ and $\mathscr{Q}_i$ are different objects**!

We can now compute the algebra of $\mathscr{Q}_i$. The key is to observe that $$[Q_i,[Q_j,{\cal O}(x)]]=[Q_i,\mathscr{Q}_j{\cal O}(x)]=\mathscr{Q}_j[Q_i,{\cal O}(x)]={\mathscr{Q}}_j\mathscr{Q}_i{\cal O}(x),\tag{6}$$
where in the second equality we used that $\mathscr{Q}_j$ just acts on the dependence in $x$ and since $Q_i$ is independent of $x$ we can just take $\mathscr{Q}_j$ from the commutator. The moral of the story is that the composition of $Q_i$ and $Q_j$ acting on ${\cal O}(x)$ through the commutator gets reflected in the product of $\mathscr{Q}_j$ and $\mathscr{Q}_i$ *in the opposite order*.

Now, on the one hand $$[[Q_i,Q_j],{\cal O}(x)]=c_{ij}^k[Q_k,{\cal O}(x)]=c_{ij}^k\mathscr{Q}_k{\cal O}(x).\tag{7}$$

On the other hand, either by using the Jacobi identity, or by explicit computation, we have

$$[[Q_i,Q_j],{\cal O}(x)] = [Q_i,[Q_j,{\cal O}(x)]-[Q_j,[Q_i,{{\cal O}(x)}]]\tag{8}$$

and in the end we can use (6)

$$[[Q_i,Q_j],{\cal O}(x)] = \mathscr{Q}_j\mathscr{Q}_i{\cal O}(x)-\mathscr{Q}_i\mathscr{Q}_j {\cal O}(x)=-[\mathscr{Q}_i,\mathscr{Q}_j]{\cal O}(x).\tag{9}$$

A comparisson of (7) and (9) shows that $$[\mathscr{Q}_i,\mathscr{Q}_j]{\cal O}(x)={\color{red}-}c_{ij}^k\mathscr{Q}_k{\cal O}(x).$$

Conclusion: if you evaluate the algebra of $Q_i$ first, and the algebra of $\mathscr{Q}_i$ separately, you will find that their structure constants differ by a minus sign.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150467/discussion-on-answer-by-gold-cft-radial-quantization-raising-and-lowering-operat); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 5):

You are seriously misunderstanding this sign flip and making a mess of your calculations because of it. You do NOT flip the sign of any commutator when acting states or operators. What the linked PSE answers are alluding to is a sign flip that occurs in the algebra of generators $A$, $B$ and $C$ and the algebra of differential operators ${\cal A}$, ${\cal B}$ and ${\cal C}$ that represent the generators.

To make this clear, let us consider the Poincar'e algebra. The algebra is (using Slava's conventions)
\begin{align}
[ M_{\mu\nu}, M_{\rho\sigma} ] &= - i ( \delta_{\mu\rho} M_{\nu\sigma} + \text{permutations}) , \\
[ M_{\mu\nu} , P_\rho ] &= - i ( \delta_{\mu\rho} P_\nu - \delta_{\nu\rho} P_\mu ) , \\
[ P_\mu , P_\nu ] &= 0 . 
\end{align}
Define derivative operators
$$
{\cal M}_{\mu\nu} =   i ( x_\mu \partial_\nu - x_\nu \partial_\mu ) , \qquad {\cal P}_\mu =   i \partial_\mu
$$
You can easily check that these differential operators satisfy the same algebra as the generators, i.e.
\begin{align}
[ {\cal M}_{\mu\nu}, {\cal M}_{\rho\sigma} ] &= - i ( \delta_{\mu\rho} {\cal M}_{\nu\sigma} + \text{permutations}) , \\
[ {\cal M}_{\mu\nu} , {\cal P}_\rho ] &= - i ( \delta_{\mu\rho} {\cal P}_\nu - \delta_{\nu\rho} {\cal P}_\mu ) , \\
[ {\cal P}_\mu , {\cal P}_\nu ] &= 0 . 
\end{align}

The sign flip you are referring to is what happens when the generators act on local operators ${\cal O}(x)$ as follows:
\begin{align}
[ M_{\mu\nu} , {\cal O}(x) ] &= \color{red}{-} {\cal M}_{\mu\nu} {\cal O}(x) , \\
[ P_\mu , {\cal O}(x) ] &= \color{red}{-} {\cal P}_\mu {\cal O}(x) .
\end{align}